# UITableView with label too wide for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a scrollable table populated with a list of cells with labels in. The rows are currently fixed heights. This table fills 1/3 screen and gives the user options for filtering the content view in other 2/3 of screen.

The text for the labels are too long and so the labels are truncated.

What is the correct way of allowing the user to view the whole label:

**1. Multiple lines**

This will ruin the look of the table. It'll be hard to read.

**2. Scroll view**

This will require disabling the cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled so that the touches are passed to the scrollview. Also, what happens when a user is trying to scroll the table but the touch point is on the UIScrollView?

Will the UIScrollView scroll or will the UITableView scroll? Is it possible for all vertical touches to make the UITableView scroll?

I'll also have to move away from didSelectRowAtIndexPath and use buttons and delegate methods right?

**3. Hold for a tooltip**

I'll have to add some kind of observer for long touches. Probably not great in terms of user experience.

Comment: Expend the cell when select?

Comment: Expand the cell to where though? I can't expand greater than the width of the table right?

Comment: Hi, one of solution could be in using of auto scroll labels like this: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink your design altogether. If your table contains filters those should be fairly easy to understand and should usually contain 1 or at most several words.

If your labels are so long that displaying them in full ruins the UI then they are probably a very bad choice for filter names, aren't they?

That said if you really want to keep the current UI the only reasonable way to do so would be to lower font size and allow all labels to occupy several lines. You would have to appropriately match the cell height so that your cells still look nice.

However, the best choice would be to rethink your UI so that you do not have to use lines of text as filter names altogether.

Comment: So you are probably right in that the filter options are too long. Imagine you return a list of documents and you have 500 filter options ordered by the number of documents that belong to each option, and those options are up to 6 words long. That's basically what I am dealing with...